# Geometry Nodes - moving point over time based on procedural vector field

Tags: animation, geometry-nodes

I'm trying to get a particle simulation running within Geometry Nodes.

I have created an underlying force field via a cosine/sine function that will define the velocity of a particle at that given point in space, visualised as such:

[image: top-down view of my procedural vector field]

I instance a bunch of points randomly in this field, and sample the force field at their respective locations in order to determine the force/velocity applied to that point.

The velocity is then be used to determine the change in position in that given frame.

My challenge is how I persist this positional change between frames. In Frame 2, I want to use the new position of the point to determine it's new force (which will be ever so slightly different from Frame 1), and move it again accordingly.

The overall effect I'm trying to achieve, is something to similar to this: https://earth.nullschool.net/

Not sure if I'm hitting the limits of Geometry Nodes here with respect to time-based animation/caching?

Comment: Could you explain the desired goal again in more detail, maybe show it with a sketch and share your blend file? As the question currently stands there, it is difficult to help, as the task is not clear from it, unfortunately. Thank you!

Comment: @quellenform apologies for the lack of clarity - I've tried to make it clearer and edited the original question. A brief summary is that I have a procedural force field, and want particles to move in accordance with that force field.

Comment: Ah, OK, that looks like an interesting project. The problem is: You only have the data of the current frame available and no access to the data of other frames. However, everything you can calculate in advance would be usable. So it depends very much on the structure and the details. But the answer could possibly be extensive, and take some time. Your blend file as a base could also help.

Comment: .blend file available here: http://filedropper.com/jH62M9BA

Comment: What I've built so far is a [Vector Field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_field). This defines the velocity of any point in the plane. Earth nullschool has an underlying vector field too. I explain the theory/math behind it in "Animating the Waves" section of the [this Medium article](https://joepavitt.medium.com/developing-a-data-driven-2d-game-with-canvas-vue-d3-js-172570bcfa4)

Comment: In my blend file, I use the normal to define the direction of movement, and move the instanced points in that direction by "speed". In the "Hardcoded Time Steps" section of my nodes, I mimic 6 time steps, moving the points a little bit at a time as per the Vector Field's normal. What I want to do is have this change in position run per frame, and not have to manually copy/paste the "Set Position" node hundreds of times

Comment: My end goal is producing a Rings of Power style Chladni Plate animation: https://twitter.com/BettiniKrisp/status/1577138013578018816?s=20&t=fZNfW7-nJiF-jgS0Z1FyCg

Comment: to be honest and if i understood you right, you want to make a simulation and on each next frame the calculation is based on the frame before, is that right? if so, you should use animation nodes which is capable of such a thing and which can handle this pretty well. You can do these things with GN but it will not be performant and very time consuming.

Comment: Yes @Chris, you are absolutely right: What you can't precisely calculate in advance, you can't represent with *Geometry Nodes*. The current example could possibly be realized with GN, but *Animation Nodes* might just be the better solution here. ...will you write an answer?

Comment: [Possibly of interest](https://entagma.com/noise-advection-with-geometry-nodes/).. although clunky, and have to agree with @Chris and quellenform  GN doesn't look like the best tool.

Comment: Thanks all so much for your help/guidance. I had tried experimenting a little with Shortest Path nodes too, and got a little closer, this works because the vector field itself is static, so paths can be calculated in advance, but going to need more time before I can share anything useful. Will take a look at animation nodes, and its great to understand where the boundaries of GN and AN exist.